# tf.shape() get wrong dimension in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I've got following error while compare two tensor(use tf equal):

```
incompatible shape [0, 1] vs [1024, 0]
```

how can the dim be zero?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code example?

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([2, 4])
y = tf.constant([2, 4])
print(tf.shape(x))
print(tf.shape(y))
tf.math.equal(x, y)
```

**Output**

```
tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=bool, numpy=array([ True,  True])>
```